# How to open a rejected URL in a webView

Tags: java, android, webview, vpn

I have a very simple android app that helps in collecting some useful websites in one place and each website loads in a webview when its button is clicked.

One of the websites is https://hadshon.edu.gov.il/ used to work fine but suddenly it doesn't load in my country "Egypt" without VPN and I assume now most probably all the Arab countries.

As most of the users using the app are from Egypt, Is there a way to bypass this and make it work again or whoever uses the application will need to use VPN?

Thank you in advance